# Keep Filter Nav Item "Active" after Ajax Completes

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, wordpress

Good Morning, I am using the Search and Filter Pro plugin for Wordpress, and as of now, I have three filter choices that shuffles team members when you click on one. ***This works just fine.***

The problem I have, I am trying to keep my active choice highlighted and Im having trouble, because the AJAX feature resets my js. The active class goes away after AJAX completes. Any ideas?

[image]

***JavaScript***

```
$(".searchandfilter ul li ul li").on("change",function(){
    $('.searchandfilter ul li ul li').each(function(){
        $(this).closest("li").addClass("active")
    });
});
```

***PHP***

```
<form data-sf-form-id='125' data-is-rtl='0' data-maintain-state='' data-results-url='http://arete.mwi.com/team/' data-ajax-url='http://arete.mwi.com/team/?sf_data=results' data-ajax-form-url='http://arete.mwi.com/?sfid=125&amp;sf_action=get_data&amp;sf_data=form' data-display-result-method='post_type_archive' data-use-history-api='1' data-template-loaded='0' data-lang-code='en' data-ajax='1' data-ajax-data-type='html' data-ajax-links-selector='.pagination a' data-ajax-target='.gridTeam' data-ajax-pagination-type='normal' data-update-ajax-url='1' data-scroll-to-pos='0' data-init-paged='1' data-auto-update='1' action='http://arete.mwi.com/team/' method='post' class='searchandfilter' id='search-filter-form-125' autocomplete='off' data-instance-count='1'>
<ul class="greenBorder">
<li class="sf-field-category" data-sf-field-name="_sft_category" data-sf-field-type="category" data-sf-field-input-type="checkbox">
<ul data-operator="or" class="">
 <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-0" data-sf-count="0" data-sf-depth="0">
                      <input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" name="_sft_category[]" checked="checked" id="sf-input-bf61a57488583828fb89988e4f217223"><label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-bf61a57488583828fb89988e4f217223">Show All</label>
                      </li>
  <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-3" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0">
 <input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="board-governance" name="_sft_category[]" id="sf-input-c22c48dbf7a852d35abd384469edaf1b"><label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-c22c48dbf7a852d35abd384469edaf1b">Board Governance</label>
  </li>
  <li class="sf-level-0 sf-item-4" data-sf-count="1" data-sf-depth="0">
  <input class="sf-input-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="management-advisory" name="_sft_category[]" id="sf-input-c373eb1330287a7a6f76a616a4016948"><label class="sf-label-checkbox" for="sf-input-c373eb1330287a7a6f76a616a4016948">Management &amp; Advisory</label></li>
 </ul>
 </li></ul></form>
 <?php if (have_posts()) {
echo '<div class="gridTeam">';
while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="teamBox">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'teamImage')); ?>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="memberTitle">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <h4><?php the_field('position'); ?>
            </h4>
            <img src="/wp-content/themes/arete/images/long-arrow-01.svg">
        </div>
    </a>
<?php }
echo '</div>';
echo '<a class="getInTouch" href="/contact">';
echo'<div class="leftPara">Think you’d make a great addition to the team? Get in Touch</div>';
echo '<div class="arrow"><img src="/wp-content/themes/arete/images/long-arrow-01.svg"></div>';
echo'</a>';
}
}
```

Comment: can you show html code and ajax ?

Comment: Here is the php code. I added this manually, since the SearchandFilter pro uses shortcodes. The AJAX is within the plugin, so I don't know where to find that so I can show you that function

Comment: problem lies within ajax because you said `AJAX feature resets my js..` so ajax is important here without seeing that code i am not sure anyone will be able to solve this issue. Also, what exactly your ajax does ?

Comment: Yeah, understood. The AJAX just filters the categories and refreshes them under `gridTeam`

Comment: @Swati there are some inline Ajax functions in the `<form>` element

Comment: yes that is causing ajax ..but you will be having complete code somewhere else ..if you found that you just need to add active class to `li` which is click